# What actions does Legion Commander's "Duel" Abillity restrict?

Tags: dota

The Legion Commander's ultimate skill "Duel" disables spells and items and 'some' passive abilities during its duration.

IE: Supposedly one of these passives is critical strikes.

Can anyone break this skill down and explain in detail what exactly you can and cannot do while under its effects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following things are disabled in **Dota1**:

- **Activable items** (all) (you and target)

  Hex,bkb,eul,manta,dagon...
- **Abilities** (all) (you and target)

  Lightning bolt,wind walk,rupture...
- **Passive abilities from items** (some,mostly orb effects and attack modifiers) (you and target)

  • Chain lightning, Maelstorm dan Mjolnir

  • True Strike, MKB

  • Maim, Sange, Heaven Halberd, dan Sange and Yasha

  • Feedback, Diffusal Blade

  • True Sight, Gem

  • Immolation, Radiance

  • Damage Block, Stout shield, PMS, Vanguard.

  • Cold attack (RANGE), Eye of skadi

  • Critical Strike, Buriza

  • Evasion, The Butterfly, Talisman, dan Heaven Halberd.

  • Bash, Cranium basher, Abysal Blade

  • Lifesteal, Mask of Death (and all other lifesteal items, except Unholy Rage - actived 
  Satanic)

  • Splash Damage, Battlefury
- **Passive abilities** (some,mostly orb effects and attack modifiers) (you and target)

  • Frostmourne, Abaddon

  • Geminate Attack, Weaver

  • Headshot, Sniper

  • Frost Attack, Dragon Knight Elder Form level 3

  • Incapacitating Bite, Broodmother

  • Mana Break, Magina

  • Geostrike, Meepo

  • Caustic Final, Sand King

  • Poison sting, Venomancer

  • Phase Shift Auto cast, Puck ( not blocked )

  • Fury Swipes, Ursa

  • Split shot, Medusa

  • Last Word, Silencer

  • Permanent invisibility, Rikimaru

  • Kraken Shell, Tide

  • Bash, Void (and all other bash skills, except Greater bash - Barathrum)

  • Blur, Mortred (and all other evasion skill, except Psedu-evasion Backtrack - 
  Darkterror)

  • Great Cleave, Sven (and all other Cleave skill, including Tidebringer - Kunkka)

  • Coup degrace, Mortred (and all other critical skills, no exceptions!)

If you ever see the animation of bashing or mana burn,or activated items they were probably activated before duel started,or by 3rd party.

As you can see castable things are disabled since it is supposed to be "autoattack" duel without interference and most orb effects and passive skills  are disabled since some of them make some enemies very hard to defeat imagine duel with ursa or slark,if they had their passive skills.

Basically "duel" is a bit weaker "doom" on you and your target,[here](http://www.playdota.com/forums/blog.php?b=1039) is the list of what doom disables.

For "duel" differences between dota1 and **dota2** refer to [this discussion](http://dev.dota2.com/showthread.php?t=118824),It appears that valve still didn't disable a lot of abilities that can be activated before the duel and grant you bonuses during the duel,like barrage,voodoo restoration...

Comment: I'l add more detailed list of things as i test them.

Comment: yes but your counterstrike works, as does any activatable item activated BEFORE the duel ie: Blademail or BKB... is your counterstrike the only passive ability that continues to work?

Comment: Passive abilities and items are only blocked on enemy hero,that's how you get the upper edge in duel

Comment: I'm fairly certain thats totally wrong. can you provide a source? As I understand it, and as I've seemed to experience it, it 'mutes' passives and items for BOTH parties...

Comment: It blocks you and your opponent,somehow i managed to pick all items that are not blocked when testing -_-

Comment: well now, that was extremely extensive, and while your link doesn't cover EVERYTHING you still get major kudos. Good work!

Comment: @Arremer I know that this question was tagged Dota, but in Dota2, desolator also gets muted. I don't know if desolator being muted is intended or a bug, but duel does definitely mute it.

Comment: At first a lot of attack modifiers weren't disabled,they patched it ad disabled most of them.Still there are a  lot of skills that are disabled/enabled differently from dota to dota2...I added the link to the discussion in the answer.